# Android SDK. setContentView cannot call activity functions

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am developing an Android app that sets to another .xml file using setContentView(R.layout.file);

The moment I do that and then try to use some of the functions in my .java file, I cannot.

How do I re-establish a connection to this java file after changing the view?

```
@Override

public boolean OnKeyUp(int arg1, KeyEvent arg2)
{

switch (arg1)
{

case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:

setContentView(R.layout.file);
return true;

}

return false;

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "...try to use some of the functions in my .java file, I cannot." Also, I would probably use a LayoutInflater (see Activity.getLayoutInflater) if you need the dynamic parts of your UI to be in XML.

Comment: If you download the YouTUbe, Facebook, Twitter, Skype, etc apps, the pages are changed with a quick sliding effect, i.e. a page change. I'm interpreting that this means they are using a `setContentView` call. When you first create a new Android SDK project you are automatically given a .java file whose name is the name of your project. How do I access functions in my .java file after calling setContentView? This .java file is where onCreate, onDestroy, and onPause are called. It's also where I import media and classes.

Comment: Do I recall my activity after setContentView?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're seeing- some transitions are device-dependent- on my Motorola phone, I couldn't find any sliding transitions, but when a new Activity is launched, there's a sort of quick zoom-in effect, so that is probably what you are seeing. I also really don't understand what the problem with calling methods on the main Activity object is that you are trying to explain. Using setContentView in places other than onCreate is not a normal thing to do - I recommend that you examine examples or open-source Android apps to find common patterns, and learn to do what you want.

Comment: [http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/) This is what I was trying to do. I have it now...

Answer (score 1):

The `setContentView` has to be done in your onCreate function and not in another function.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: setContentView has already been called in onCreate to bring up the main xml file. Once the app is loaded, I want other .xml files to be brought up using setContentView. How to I regain the ability to use the functions in my original .java file? i.e. How would you load another page on a button click while still being able to use your original functions?